# google.maps.Map is not a constructor

Tags: html, typescript, google-maps

I am trying to create map markers with html as shown here: (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/advanced-markers/html-markers#maps_advanced_markers_html-typescript)
I am working in angular and seem to have missed the mark somewhere.
My issue is that the application is just creating the default markers at the given coordinates but ignoring the html inside the  class. Any idea how to get this to work in angular16?
I am also running into the issue:

```
main.ts:6 ERROR TypeError: google.maps.Map is not a constructor
    at google-maps.mjs:252:34
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:368:26)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:129:43)
    at NgZone.runOutsideAngular (core.mjs:10979:28)
    at GoogleMap.ngOnInit (google-maps.mjs:251:26)
    at callHookInternal (core.mjs:4024:14)
    at callHook (core.mjs:4051:13)
    at callHooks (core.mjs:4006:17)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.mjs:3956:9)
    at selectIndexInternal (core.mjs:11780:17)
```

MapComponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-property-map',
  templateUrl: 'map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    this.initMap();
  }
  @ViewChild(MapComponent) infoWindow: MapComponent | undefined;
  property : any;

  
  constructor( ){}
  async initMap() {
    const  Map  = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");

    const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps") as google.maps.MapsLibrary;
    const map = new Map(document.getElementById("map") as HTMLElement, {
    zoom: 11,
    center: { lat:-33.95719133500393,  lng: 25.600222789050612 },
    mapId: "4504f8b37365c3d0",
    });

    for (const property of this.properties) {
      const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map,
        position: property.position,
        title: property.description,
      });

      marker.addListener('click', () => {
        this.toggleHighlight(marker, property);
      });
    }
  }

  toggleHighlight(marker: google.maps.Marker, property: any) {
    if (marker.getZIndex() === 1) {
      marker.setZIndex(null);
      // Remove the highlight class or handle it based on your CSS classes
    } else {
      marker.setZIndex(1);
      // Add the highlight class or handle it based on your CSS classes
    }
  }
    
    buildContent(property: any) {
     const content = document.createElement("div");
     content.classList.add(property);
    content.innerHTML = ``
      
    return content;
  }

  
   properties = [{
    address: 'Allister Miller Dr, Walmer, Gqeberha, 6070',
    description: 'Airport Reservoir',
    price: '$ 3,889,000',
    type: 'building',
    size: 300,
    position: {
      lat: -33.9864000933515, 
      lng: 25.61399429260211,
    },
```

MapComponent.html

```
<div id="map" style="height: 500px;"></div>

<google-map>
    <div class="icon">
                            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-icon" [ngClass]="'fa-' + property.type" [title]="property.type"></i>
                            <span class="fa-sr-only">{{ property.type }}</span>
                              </div>
                              <div class="details">
                                  <div class="price">{{ property.price }}</div>
                                  <div class="address">{{ property.address }}</div>
                                  <div class="features">
                                      <div>
                                          <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-bed fa-lg bed" title="bedroom"></i>
                                          <span class="fa-sr-only">bedroom</span>
                                          <span>{{ property.bed }}</span>
                                      </div>
                                      <div>
                                          <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-bath fa-lg bath" title="bathroom"></i>
                                          <span class="fa-sr-only">bathroom</span>
                                          <span>{{ property.bath }}</span>
                                      </div>
                                      <div>
                                          <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-ruler fa-lg size" title="size"></i>
                                          <span class="fa-sr-only">size</span>
                                          <span>{{ property.size }} ft<sup>2</sup></span>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                        </div>
</google-map>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Map` is a property of `MapsLibrary`, as documented in [MapsLibrary interface](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/top-level#MapsLibrary)

You need to use the Map object from the imported library (code in the documentation uses object destructuring).

Compare your code with the documentation:

**Documentation**

```
const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps") as google.maps.MapsLibrary;
const map = new Map(document.getElementById("map") as HTMLElement, {
    zoom: 11,
    center,
    mapId: "4504f8b37365c3d0",
  });
```

**Your code:**

```
const Map = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map') as HTMLElement, {
      zoom: 10,
      center: { lat:-33.95719133500393,  lng: 25.600222789050612 },
      // mapId: '4504f8b37365c3d0',
    });
```

Comment: I see. Any idea why I am still getting the type error in my browser after adding the code from the documentation?

Comment: As explained, the code in the original post does not match the documentation. If you updated your code and it still does not work, please post an update to your question.

Comment: I have posted an update to my code.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Kind regards,
Keenan